# Connection refused occured when I trying to connect to Redis that run in Docker in WSL2 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: java, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Never happened before, but today I upgrade Windows preview version, and an exception occured (Connection Refused: connect).

Redis runs in a Docker container and Docker runs in WSL2 (Ubuntu 18.04), and also there are a Mongodb database and a Mysql database running in docker.
I cannot connect to Mongodb(by Java) or Redis (by Jedit) but Mysql is well (by Navicat or Java).

Then, I write a simple java program with Jedis to connect to Redis, it works failed in Windows but successful in WSL2. And I also connect to Redis with telnet command, it works successful in Windows and WSL2.

```
Windows Version: 10.0.20175.1000, Insider Preview, Build 20175.re_prerelease.200717-1349
Linux in WSL2: Ubuntu 18.04
Docker Version: 19.03.8
Mongodb and Redis: latest
Mysql: 5.6
Jedis: 2.7.2
```

```java
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:155)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:83)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:94)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.set(BinaryClient.java:100)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Client.set(Client.java:29)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.set(Jedis.java:65)
    at com.ty.tissue.config.TissueConfig.main(TissueConfig.java:105)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:149)
    ... 6 more
```

help me, thanks.

Comment: Formerly, I run the Redis in Docker use default config file, it works. when the exception happened, I tried to specify the redis.config file via `-v` argument and set `bind 0.0.0.0` and `prototected-mode no`